# how to use Mysql with Visual Studio on macbook

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

How can I use MySQL with Visual Studio ? I want to use C# for windows Desktop application development with MySQL server. I'm getting an error while using VM and docker:

Comment: This is not enough information to help you with.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)